# Set a default checkstyle profile automatically

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, checkstyle

I'm configuring an Eclipseinstallation for a large number of users and want to configure it as complete as possible.

Its Eclipse 3.7 and I have checkstyle 5.6 installed, I've also created a plugin with a custom configuration. Now, I want to somehow set this custom checkstyle configuration to be the default setting in Eclipse for a new user. How can I do that?

I tried to set it in preferences, and export the preferences. But that doesnt seem to set the checkstyle profile.

I'm actually starting to consider converting the CS profile to a Eclipse code formatter, since that will easily allow me to set it as default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some settings are stored in the workspace so I'm afraid you can't finish your job without delivering a default workspace.